# Piezo Beeper sound output is too low

Tags: pi-zero, python-3, gpiozero

I need to use some kind of indicator for errors and warnings, I thought a piezo beeper would be perfect since I have one lying around, I did some research online and found out that I can connect it through GPIO and then use python to use it, via the gpiozero module but it barely makes a sound, the best way to describe it is a small 'pop' sound, why is this? Do I need to adjust frequency or something? It's connected to Pin 9 (Ground) and GPIO 17. nothing else is connected.

Code:

```
from gpiozero import Buzzer
from time import sleep

buzzer = Buzzer(17)

while True:
    buzzer.beep()
    sleep(1)
```

Comment: What's the voltage rating for your piezoelectric buzzer. If it's more than 3.3V you'll need a two transistor switch to activate it (at a higher a Vcc voltage)

Answer (score 1):

The docs for [Buzzer](https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api_output.html#buzzer) says:

> This interface is only capable of simple on/off commands, and is not
>   capable of playing a variety of tones (see
>   [TonalBuzzer](https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api_output.html#tonalbuzzer)).

Answer (score 0):

It is generally inadvisable to put DC across a piezoelectric device. A series capacitor may help with the pop.

The voltage swing of the Pi is very low - running the buzzer in push-pull will increase volume (and eliminate the DC problem). This requires 2 GPIO pins (or extra circuitry).

<s>If the “buzzer “ is intended to run from DC (using internal circuitry) you are using the wrong code.</s>

The "beep" of buzzer seems to be a simple on/off.

Comment: The buzzer is a typical one you see used in desktop computer motherboards, not sure if it's active or passive though

Comment: @Myronaz You should probably use class gpiozero.TonalBuzzer